# Identify the cable connector

Tags: cable, connector

Please identify this cable connector by model/part number/supplier. It is a cable between a control box and microprocessor. One photo for scale shows the connector next to an RJ45.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: do you have any info about the devices its connected to?

Comment: I think that the next plug up from RJ45 is RJ61, but I cant find anyone selling them.

Answer (score 1):

Manufacturer: TE Connectivity AMP Connectors
Manufacturer Product Number: 5-520424-3
Description: CONN PLUG 8POS SDL 24-26AWG RND